# Serenity-BDD screenplay REST interactions with a request specification

Tags: serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity, serenity-platform

I want to send a post request in my test using the format:

```
RequestSpecification requestSpecification = RestAssured.given()
                                                            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                                                            .body(taskDetailsFormSubmission);

actor.attemptsTo(
    Post.to(path).with(requestSpecification)
);
```

I am creating a RequestSpecification and parsing a JSON file in one of my directories.

The problem however is that `with()` only accepts the type `RestQueryFunction`. Looking at the interface:

```
public interface RestQueryFunction extends Function<RequestSpecification,RequestSpecification> {}
```

I'm just not really sure how to apply the RequestSpecification to the POST request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Function<RequestSpecification,RequestSpecification>` is a case of `Function<T,R>` java functional interface.

The method `with()` requires `RestQueryFunction` means you have to provide an implementation of `RestQueryFunction` which might be a class, anonymous class or lambda expression. It follows the rule:

- Parameter is RequestSpecification.
- Return type is RequestSpecification.

You could try

```
actor.attemptsTo(
    Post.to(path).with(r -> r.contentType(ContentType.JSON) 
                           .body(taskDetailsFormSubmission);
    )
);
```